# Geolocation callback after user approves/denies location services

Tags: javascript, callback, geolocation, bootstrap-modal, settimeout

If this has already been answered, please point me in the right direction. I've done some searching but haven't found a definite answer.

Basically, I'm using using geolocation to pull nearby dealers from a database and then displaying them in a popup window (bootstraps modal).

Here's some of the relevant code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, error);  

    //show popup after 30s
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.mod-popup').modal('show');
    }, 30000);
}
else{
    //destroy popup
    $('.mod-popup').remove();
}

function showPosition(position) {
    gmap_location_lookup(position.coords.latitude+', '+position.coords.longitude,'100','');
}

function error(err) {
    $('.mod-popup').remove();
}
```

When the browser dialog box comes up and the user clicks 'Allow Location Access' everything works as planned. When the user clicks 'DO NOT Allow Location Access' the popup gets destroyed. The issue I'm having is that when the user doesn't respond to the browser dialog, the popup is still getting displayed without any relevant info (blank list of locations). I'm assuming this has to do with me using the setTimeout function. What is the better way to go about only firing off the popup after 30s IF the user allows location services?

Comment: You can try to ask for permission again maybe it will return false or something.

Comment: Check docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API

Comment: the example in that link doesn't seem to work properly... when clicking 'enable geolocation' console says: Permission currently denied; future features of the Permissions API will allow us to request permission here.

Currently you have to reset the permission state using the browser UI.

In Firefox it is done with Tools > Page Info > Permissions > Access Your Location.

Comment: As for 'revoke permission' console says: TypeError: navigator.permissions.revoke is not a function

Comment: I've added an answer with [code](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/XqEZeV) but then read again your question, and the answer is that you can't invoke an action on closing permission popup, you can also have grant or deny events.

Comment: I appreciate the response, it is help. Though when I click 'Do Not Allow' location services, I am not seeing the "Denied" message appear.

Comment: Is your error function being invoked?

Comment: Weird, in Google Chrome I've got message Denied or location, In my code the onchange event is invoked when I've clicked deny button, but not on close.

Comment: Using the codepen provided in Firefox I am able to get location, but no denied message. As for Chrome, neither the location or denied message is displayed